# Script does not show output in Firefox, but works in snippet

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know why, but when I test my calculator the result doesn't appear in the third input. Can you find the error? I tried!

It's a sales tax calculator. First I enter the price, and then the third input should give me the final price with the tax of 11.5%.  The second input is optional; there I can enter a discount.

In my FireFox browser this doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Calculadora IVU</title>
</head>

<body>


        <div class="app">

<h1> Calculadora de IVU 11.5% </h1>
</br>
</br>
<form name="forms" id="forma">

 <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label id="valor">Entra el valor</label>
        </br>
        <input type="text" id="cajaprincipal" name="txts" size=25>
        </br>
        <label id="entrad"> Entra algun descuento </label>
        <input type="number" name="jupiter" id="adri" size=18>
        </br>
        <label id="preciofinal"> Total con el IVU 11.5% es: </label>
        <input type="number" name="resul" id="res">
        </br>
        </br>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <INPUT TYPE="button" id ="boto" NAME="one" VALUE="7" OnClick="forms.txts.value += '7'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" id="boto" NAME="two" VALUE="8" OnCLick="forms.txts.value += '8'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button"  id="boto" NAME="three" VALUE="9" OnClick="forms.txts.value  += '9'">
        <br>
        <INPUT TYPE="button" id ="boto" NAME="four" VALUE=" 4 " OnClick="forms.txts.value += '4'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" id ="boto" NAME="five" VALUE="  5  " OnCLick="forms.txts.value += '5'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" id ="boto" NAME="six" VALUE="  6  " OnClick="forms.txts.value += '6'">

        <br>
        <INPUT TYPE="button" id ="boto" NAME="seven" VALUE="  1  " OnClick="forms.txts.value+= '1'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" id ="boto" NAME="eight" VALUE="  2 " OnCLick="forms.txts.value += '2'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" id ="boto" NAME="nine" VALUE="  3 " OnClick="forms.txts.value += '3'">

        <br>
       <INPUT TYPE="button" id ="boto" NAME="zero" VALUE="  0  " OnClick="forms.txts.value += '0'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" id ="boto" NAME="plus" VALUE="." OnClick="forms.txts.value += '.'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" id ="boto" NAME="plus" VALUE="  +  " OnClick="forms.txts.value += '+ '">

        <br>
       <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="clear" id=clearb VALUE="c"  OnClick="forms.txts.value = ''">


      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
        </br>
        <input type="button" id="calcular" value="CALCULAR" onClick='CalculateIVU();'>
        </br>
         </br>
          </br>
           </br>
            </br>
             </br>
              </br>
               </br>
                </br>
                 </br>
                 <p id="calabaza"> <i> Calabaza was here <i>  </p>


                 
  </form>
 
 </div>

<script language = "javascript">
    
    function CalculateIVU() {
      var price = document.forms.txts.value;
      var descuento = document.forms.jupiter.value;
      var loca = descuento /100;
      var sum = eval(price); // at this point we know price can be eval()ed
      var tax = 0.115 * sum;
      var final = sum + tax;
      var beta = loca * final;
      var alpha = final - beta;
      document.getElementById("res").value = alpha.toFixed(2);  // round
    }

    </script>

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This appears to work on your snippet...

Comment: Yeah I know, but when I test in my firefox browser dont works...

Comment: Please give your question a descriptive name.

Comment: Please do not use 'forms' as form name. document.forms is a built-in property which holds the array of all forms inside your html. Please use any other name for your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a [Content Security Policy (CSP) error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Security/CSP) on the line with `eval`:

> Error: call to eval() blocked by CSP

You should have noticed this in the console. This kind of error is raised when you include a `meta` tag like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
      content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'" />
```

As stated in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives#script-src):

> #### `script-src`
>
> The `script-src` directive specifies valid sources for JavaScript. When either the `script-src` or the `default-src` directive is included, inline script and `eval()` are disabled unless you specify `'unsafe-inline'` and `'unsafe-eval'`, respectively. In Chrome 49 and later, `'script-src http'` will match both HTTP and HTTPS.

So either you'd have to remove the `meta` tag, or add the `'unsafe-eval'` specification to it, or better: replace your call to `eval` with code that does not produce this CSP error. In fact, you should not have to use `eval` for your use case. Just apply the unitary `+` to the string to convert it to number.

So replace:

```
  var sum = eval(price);
```

with:

```
  var sum = +price;
```

In a snippet on StackOverflow the original code works because the `meta` tags are silently moved out of the `head` tag into the `body` tag, which breaks the CSP directive.

Comment: Hey thanks. Sorry for my grammar. It's not my first language. I fix the problem thanks to you.